# Boring bar holder for lathe tool post

Tags: machining

I want to be able to hold a 1/2" diameter shank boring bar on my existing lathe tool post but don't know how to buy the correct one.

The post we have is a Phase II 250-111: https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/09044017?item=09044017

The boring bars we have a 1/2" shank diameter. I'm hoping to get a different brand for the tool holder because it is cheaper. Which of the options below would fit? I'm confused by the OXA or AXA as I don't see that specified in the post description from Phase II.
https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/30579627
https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/30574867

or even
[https://www.amazon.com/Quick-Change-Boring-Holder-250-004/dp/B07THWWQQD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07THWWQQD)

or an even cheaper option:
[https://www.amazon.com/Boring-Bar-Holder-1-2/dp/B077V5HKNR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077V5HKNR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lathe quick change tool posts or  QCTP are sized for the lathe your using it on, particularly, the swing.

0XA = UP TO ~8"
AXA = 9-12"
BAX = 12-15"
and so forth...

Looks like you have a phase 2, 100 series post, or an AXA sized tool post, so you would be looking for AXA tool holders. I believe a standard AXA boring bar holder is for 3/4" shank so you'd need a bushing. You can also purchase a standard tool holder that has a v grove at the bottom of the tool slot that can hold your boring bar.